# Unity freezes when attempting to modify RGB colors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, renderer, gameobject

I am trying to modify the Color32 RGB values of a Unity Renderer component gradually over time, but whenever I play the game in Unity, it just freezes the program and I have to close out. I am certain that it is because of how I am trying to modify it, but I do not know where I am wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
void degradeGradually(Renderer ren){
    float time = Time.time; 
    Color32 col;
    while(((Color32)ren.material.color).r > 89f){
        if (Time.time - time > .025f) {
            time = Time.time;
            col = new Color32 ((byte)(((Color32)ren.material.color).r - 1f), (byte)(((Color32)ren.material.color).g - 1f), (byte)(((Color32)ren.material.color).b - 1f), 255);
            ren.material.color = col; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you prolly calling  `degradeGradually` from Update... your call is blocking update thread ... the `Time.time` is never changed ... just replace `while` with `if` and make `float time = Time.time; ` a field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `while` loop in this method never terminates and thus the `Update` that calls it never completes. This freezes your game.

One possible solution is turning this method into a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) (the documentation's first example is remarkably similar to your code!) and putting a `return yield null` at the end of your while loop:

```
IEnumerator degradeGradually(Renderer ren){
    float time = Time.time; 
    Color32 col;
    while(((Color32)ren.material.color).r > 89f){
        if (Time.time - time > .025f) {
            time = Time.time;
            col = new Color32 ((byte)(((Color32)ren.material.color).r - 1f), (byte)(((Color32)ren.material.color).g - 1f), (byte)(((Color32)ren.material.color).b - 1f), 255);
            ren.material.color = col; 
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

And then where you call it,

```
 // Instead of degradeGradually(r);
 StartCoroutine(degradeGradually(r));
```

And if you need to do something directly after the degrading happens, you can add it to the bottom of `degradeGradually`.

```
            ...
            ren.material.color = col; 
        }

        yield return null;
    }

    DoStuffAfterDegrade();
}
```

Also, color component values range from `0f` to `1f` so you'll want to decrease them by something smaller than 1f each time. As written, you'll fade to black on the first frame you get inside the `if` statement. You also might have to clamp your components between `0f`-`1f` if Unity gives you any trouble about putting in negative numbers.

Comment: This should fix the freezing issue. On the other hand, it looks you should have asked OP he/she is trying to do because this looks like something the lerping functions such as `Color.Lerp` function should be used for.

Comment: Thank you very much, both of your suggestions worked. the IEnumerator explanation allowed me to understand how it works and utilizing Color.Lerp allowed me to do it in a much easier way, so thank you to both of you.